# Quantile regression and mean log predictive score

Tags: time-series, model-evaluation, quantile-regression, scoring-rules

During my research, I got stuck with an evaluation of my quantile regression models (qr). I have two QR models that model some economic variable in time. I would like to evaluate which model is better by the log score. What I would like to do is run one-out predictions: for instance, fit the models using data till time t and predict t+1; repeat till I run out of data. Then measure and compare their predictive power with the log predictive score.

What I found is that the mean log predictive score should be calculated using this formula:
$\frac{1}{N}\sum \log{p(y_{t+1}|y_{-1},M)}$ where $y_{-1}$ are data used to fit the model $M$ till time $t$ and $y_{t+1}$ is the realization of the economic variable at time $t+1$.

However, quantile regression provides me with a quantile function only. I do not know the probability density. So far, I approximate the density by the means of the Epanechnikov kernel. Is there a better way?

Thanks for your help :) btw, I am not a statistician but I guess you noticed already